# Responsive image not working bootstrap

Tags: wordpress, image, twitter-bootstrap

I tried doing it but still it won't work. can anyone please tell me.
I want the logo image to be responsive. that is when the image is opened on a mobile device it should automatically resize the logos.

http://www.bootply.com/IphpJ1sbwL

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="yourImage.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Nice img">
```

You should assign `.img-responsive` to your `img` tag not to `div` tag.

**Edit 1:**
ovewrite `.img-responsive`  class afer your `bootstrap.css` or bootstap-min.css on your page like below and assing .img-responsive to your ALL images.

```
.img-responsive {
   display: inline;
}
```

See this answer for better understanding. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19449583/1848929

Comment: I tried assigning to img, but it will disturbed everything. see here: http://tesla-pv.com

Comment: which is your logo? There are three images.

Comment: I want all three of them aligned and responsive.

Comment: it worked for alignment only, but images are still not responsive on mobile.

Comment: @arslion try to add this inline style to your ALL images : `style="width:100%; height:auto;"`