# Auto adjust height of images in list to always stay in one line

Tags: html, css, tabs

I have a list (functions as a menu) with images in it. The images have different proportions, some are square, others are rectangular.

I'm having troubles keeping them on the same line, when the viewport gets smaller (mobile). I'm also using bootstrap to make the tabs.

What I have now on smaller viewports (mobile):
[image]

And this is what I want it to look like:
[image]

```css
.ProdText_Att_Img {
  max-height: 75px !important;
  padding: 10px;
}

.ProdText_barekraftLogoer {
  display: table;
  /* Allow the centering to work */
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tab-content {
  padding-top: 25px;
}

.ProdText_bare_UL {
  white-space: nowrap !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}

.ProdText_bare_LI {
  display: inline !important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .ProdText_Att_Img {
    max-height: 45px !important;
    padding: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ProdText_barekraftLogoer">
  <ul class="ProdText_bare_UL nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="ProdText_bare_LI" role="presentation">
      <a href="#tab_1" aria-controls="tab_1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        <img class="ProdText_Att_Img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/44/Recycle001.svg/2000px-Recycle001.svg.png">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="ProdText_bare_LI" role="presentation">
      <a href="#tab_2" aria-controls="tab_2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        <img class="ProdText_Att_Img" src="https://www.bluesign.com/inc/template/th_blue/images/logo.png">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="ProdText_bare_LI" role="presentation">
      <a href="#tab_3" aria-controls="tab_3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        <img class="ProdText_Att_Img" src="http://www.fairtrade.no/fileadmin/system/img/fairtradenorge_logo_214x260.png">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="ProdText_bare_LI" role="presentation">
      <a href="#tab_5" aria-controls="tab_5" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        <img class="ProdText_Att_Img" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2454/5197/files/biodegradable-bag-4_medium.png?v=1509802905">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="ProdText_bare_LI" role="presentation">
      <a href="#tab_6" aria-controls="tab_6" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        <img class="ProdText_Att_Img" src="https://www.uncpress.org/archive/farmfreshnorthcarolina.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/201101_31_Animal-Welfare-Approved.jpg">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="ProdText_bare_LI" role="presentation">
      <a href="#tab_8" aria-controls="tab_8" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        <img class="ProdText_Att_Img" src="https://www.fairwear.org/wp-content/themes/fairwear/dist/img/fair-wear-foundation-logo.png">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="ProdText_bare_LI" role="presentation">
      <a href="#tab_4" aria-controls="tab_4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        <img class="ProdText_Att_Img" src="https://www.centexbel.be/sites/default/files/styles/full_width_preserve_ratio_desktop/public/media/image/std100logo.jpg?itok=htVK89Mr">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If you always want the images to be next to each other set the container width to `width: 100vw`

Comment: Add display: flex; to class .ProdText_bare_UL and the images will scale automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems you will face on mobiles is that your images with this approach will be unreadable and to small for the users to recognize them.

But if you are still going to follow this path, please look at the following post

[Responsive images inline-block in a div with Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448316/responsive-images-inline-block-in-a-div-with-bootstrap)

It describes a similar problem to yours, just with 3 images you will have to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: I have considered this, but i wanted to at least see what it looked like before i decide to drop the one line idea. thanks for the link!

Comment: This did work, and in this case, the size of the images ended up pretty good, thanks!

Comment: Also you should resize the images and provide static images for each device form big screens to smaller screens.Don't just use the responsive property for images, if you do so, it will take a long time for mobile user with a slow connection to load your images.For example a 800px image.

Answer (score 0):

I added a sytle to your div that has `width: 100%`. It is possible to add this also in the CSS wiche would like this:

```
ProdText_barekraftLogoer {
    width: 100%;
}
```

The following is your code snippet with the mentioned changes:

```css
.ProdText_Att_Img {
  max-height: 75px !important;
  padding: 10px;
}

.ProdText_barekraftLogoer {
  display: table;
  /* Allow the centering to work */
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tab-content {
  padding-top: 25px;
}

.ProdText_bare_UL {
  white-space: nowrap !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}

.ProdText_bare_LI {
  display: inline !important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .ProdText_Att_Img {
    max-height: 45px !important;
    padding: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ProdText_barekraftLogoer" style="width: 100%;">


  <ul class="ProdText_bare_UL nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="ProdText_bare_LI" role="presentation">
      <a href="#tab_1" aria-controls="tab_1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        <img class="ProdText_Att_Img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/44/Recycle001.svg/2000px-Recycle001.svg.png">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="ProdText_bare_LI" role="presentation">
      <a href="#tab_2" aria-controls="tab_2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        <img class="ProdText_Att_Img" src="https://www.bluesign.com/inc/template/th_blue/images/logo.png">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="ProdText_bare_LI" role="presentation">
      <a href="#tab_3" aria-controls="tab_3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        <img class="ProdText_Att_Img" src="http://www.fairtrade.no/fileadmin/system/img/fairtradenorge_logo_214x260.png">
      </a>
    </li>

    <li class="ProdText_bare_LI" role="presentation">
      <a href="#tab_5" aria-controls="tab_5" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        <img class="ProdText_Att_Img" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2454/5197/files/biodegradable-bag-4_medium.png?v=1509802905">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="ProdText_bare_LI" role="presentation">
      <a href="#tab_6" aria-controls="tab_6" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        <img class="ProdText_Att_Img" src="https://www.uncpress.org/archive/farmfreshnorthcarolina.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/201101_31_Animal-Welfare-Approved.jpg">
      </a>
    </li>

    <li class="ProdText_bare_LI" role="presentation">
      <a href="#tab_8" aria-controls="tab_8" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        <img class="ProdText_Att_Img" src="https://www.fairwear.org/wp-content/themes/fairwear/dist/img/fair-wear-foundation-logo.png">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="ProdText_bare_LI" role="presentation">
      <a href="#tab_4" aria-controls="tab_4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        <img class="ProdText_Att_Img" src="https://www.centexbel.be/sites/default/files/styles/full_width_preserve_ratio_desktop/public/media/image/std100logo.jpg?itok=htVK89Mr">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.